# Как задать постоянный размер скролла странице?

Tags: html, iframe, прокрутка

У меня на странице находится iframe, размер содержания которого меняется из-за анимаций и нужно чтобы на нём постоянно висел скролл, а не то появлялся то исчезал. Думаю тут код самой страницы ни к чему.
  Пока что стоит костыль в виде невидимого блока на месте, до которого необходим скролл.

Comment: <iframe scrolling="yes">...</iframe>

Comment: Пробовал, но скролл всё равно не всегда стоит.